# Erro na requisição com um objeto complexo

Tags: android, xml, soap

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição para um webservice.

Observe que pelo SoapUI ele funciona normalmente[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, pelo android passando exatamente os mesmos dados[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece o seguinte erro:

> ```
>         SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: O servidor não pôde ler a solicitação. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Erro no documento XML (1, 297). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: O tipo especificado não foi reconhecido: nome='anyType', espaço para nome='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', em <pDenuncia xmlns='http://localhost'>.
>         em Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read19_Denuncia_Grid_BD(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
> ```
>
> em Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read50_Solicitar_Denuncia()
>      em System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>      -- - Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas-- -
>       em System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>      em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>      -- - Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas-- -
>       em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>      em System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@ce52050

Lembrando que o objeto tem o mesmo nome e as mesmas propriedades, tanto no projeto do web service, quanto no projeto android.

Answer (score 0):

`public class SuaClasse implements Serializable`

E caso sua classe possua outras classes, também será necessário adicionar o `implements Serializable` nelas

Comment: Tentei tanto com Serializable quanto com KvmSerializable e não deu certo